# Hide the url shown in WebViews in iOS when signing in using ADB2C and react-native-msal

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**Problem**:
I want to hide the url that is shown in the WebViews when logging in using ADB2C in iOS.

**Platform**: React Native

**library**: react-native-msal

[The Url Shown in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMEB1.jpg)

**Things I tried**: I tried changing the parameters
ios_webviewType?: Ios_MSALWebviewType;
and
ios_presentationStyle?: Ios_ModalPresentationStyle;

But did not find a way to hide the URL.
(Even though wkwebiew hid the url, Google does not support it)

**Expected Result**: The WebViews should open for selection of account without any url in the top.

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible with the type of web view google requires in iOS.